# How to plot two arrays in a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have two arrays that are the number of faculty and number of publications and I am trying to make a histogram of those two arrays.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.1/topics/hist

```
RefPub = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
FacMem = c(28,4,3,4,4,2,1,0,2,1,1)
a = c(0,10)
b = c(0,30)
info = rbind(FacMem, RefPub)
info2 = rbind(RefPub,FacMem)
hist(info,
     ylim=a,
     xlim=b)
hist(info2,
     ylim=b,
     xlim=a)
```

I made two different histograms because I was expecting `rbind` to have one argument be X and one be Y but that wasn't the case. What I get is a histogram with mixed axis on both histograms. With `rbind` I am trying to combine my two arrays. What I am expecting is to get a histogram of the number of publications per faculity member which is in the `FacMem` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for sounds like a bar plot rather than a histogram.

```
RefPub = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
FacMem = c(28,4,3,4,4,2,1,0,2,1,1)

barplot(FacMem, names.arg=RefPub)
```

With `ggplot2`,

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(RefPub=RefPub, 
                FacMem=FacMem)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=RefPub, y=FacMem)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:10) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,5,10,15,20))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Though is there any way to add more numbers on the y-axis for the ggplot version? It goes from 0 to 10 to 20 so is there any way to go by increments of 5? Same with the x-axis but going by increments of 1?

Comment: Play around with `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()`. I have edited just to give an example.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate it! I would give an upvote but I don't have enough reputation to do so.